# how to Calculating Discount Percentage of a given discounted price

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

this is my code but error is message : divison by zero

```
  <?php $percent = (($topsell->prodcut_price - $topsell->discount_price)*100) /$topsell->prodcut_price ;?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you have made a mistake in:

```
$topsell->prodcut_price
```

maybe:

```
$topsell->product_price
```

Anyway, check variable if it equal to zero before dividing on it.

Comment: thnx for your comment